# some confusions in machine learning

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two confusions when I use machine learning algorithm. At first, I have to say that I just use it.

1. There are two categories A and B, if I want to pick as many as A from their mixture, what kind of algorithm should I use ( no need to consider the number of samples) . At first I thought it should be a classification algorithm. And I use for example boost decision tree in a package TMVA, but someone told me that BDT is a regression algorithm indeed.
2. I find when I have coarse data. If I analysis it ( do some combinations ...) before I throw it to BDT, the result is better than I throw the coarse data into BDT. Since the coarse data contains every information, why do I need analysis it myself?

Is you are not clear, please just add a comment. And hope you can give me any advise.

Comment: for question 2 can you attach an example of your "coarse data" together with your "analysed data"? and also the parameters you used with your classifier (e.g n_classifier, max_depth etc)

Comment: My data is some particles. We know that a particle have momentum, which is px, py, pz and e, means x direction momentum, y direction ... and energy. This is the coarse data. For different categories A and B, the mass of A and B is different. So we can combine that mass = sqrt(e^2-px^2-py^2-pz^2). Also, we can use four momentum( the coarse data) to combine other meaningful variable, like cos=pz/sqrt(px^2+py^2+pz^2).  As you can see, all the "analysed data" are combinations of "coarse data", but "analysed data" is a better input for BDT.

Comment: The parameters are: "!H:!V:NTrees=850:MinNodeSize=2.5%:MaxDepth=5:BoostType=AdaBoost:AdaBoostBeta=0.5:UseBaggedBoost:BaggedSampleFraction=0.5:SeparationType=GiniIndex:nCuts=20" For BDT.

Answer (score 1):

For 2, you have to perform some manipulation on data and feed it to perform better because from it is not built into algorithm to `analyze`. It only looks at data and `classifies`. The problem of analysis as you put it is called `feature selection` or `feature engineering` and it has to be done by hand (of course unless you are using some kind of technique that learns features eg. deep learning). In machine learning, it has been seen a lot of times that manipulated/engineered features perform better than raw features.

For 1, I think BDT can be used for regression as well as classification. This looks like a classification problem (to choose or not to choose). Hence you should use a classification algorithm

Comment: Thanks a lot,this is what I want to know. But I still can't understand, after feature selection we lose some information actually, why can we get a better result. In my opinion, if a ML algorithm is perfect, it should analysis automatically. Another problem is that, when I put more variables(the combinations) , the result is better. It seems a little foolish, because it seems indicate me to put all the combinations. Last question, in scikit-learn, the decision tree algorithm default criterions are gini and entropy. Can I write a new criterion myself like: number of A category / all the number

Comment: @insomnia After feature selection we lose some information, but that information doesn't matter. I see it as not losing information, but rather focusing on more important parts of information (like giving more weightage). For ex : you would want to know a person's weight when trying to guess his gender but not what he ate last night.

Comment: Also, you would have read about "No free lunch theorem". ML is not magic, things have to be fine-tuned and ML algorithms cannot analyze automatically (most of them). The different combinations of features can be taken automatically into account by using algorithms like SVM (gaussian kernel) or neural networks, but even they require tweakings.

Comment: Yes there is a limit to adding combinations, and after a while the accuracies will hit a upper limit. In your case you might be adding independent combinations and hence improvement. Once correlation in those features start increasing, improvements will be less. Non-linear SVM with gaussian kernel considers all possible polynomial combinations of featues. You might want to look at that, if that performs better. 

PS : Upvote, if you feel answer is worth it.

Comment: wow, "No free lunch theorem" and non-linear SVM with gaussian kernel is exactly what I want. Thanks for your pro answer. And in fact I upvoted with your first answer but I am in a low reputation so it doesn't display.

Comment: Just a heads up, Gaussian kernel requires more data generally. You can accept the answer :P

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure ML is the approach for your problem? In case it is, some classification algorithms would be:
logistic regression, neural networks, support vector machines,desicion trees just to name a few.

Comment: I think ML should be a way. But for classification algorithm decision tree, it just divided samples to several categories. If the samples number in each categories are different, even not in the same order, this division will much bias to the category with more samples. ( For example if the criterion is entropy ) So I said "pick" a category from their mixture. I think it's a little different.

Comment: And I never use others, let me try them first.